# Tuning type setting on Yamaha CP5?

Tags: keyboard, temperament, just-intonation

I would like to change the tuning type on a Yamaha CP5. I could not find anything relevant in the manual, surprisingly, since cheaper models (like P-140) routinely have this setting. There is a thread indicating it was possible ([Non-equal temperament on high-end Yamaha digital pianos?](http://www.pianoworld.com/forum/ubbthreads.php/topics/1613921/Non-equal%20temperament%20on%20high-.html) at pianoworld.com) but no relevant reference is given. There is just 13 option pages, one of them is Master Tune (440Hz), but I did not see anything related to tuning. Could someone confirm CP-5 does/does not make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the manuals and documentation for the Yamaha CP5 can be found at this link:

http://download.yamaha.com/search/product/?language=en&site=usa.yamaha.com&category_id=16365&product_id=1048812

The answer to your question is on page 27 of the English-language **Reference Manual** at the above link -- it is ***not*** found in the **Owners Manual**, which is a separate document.

The **Reference Manual** says:

> Page 3: On-screen name (and full name) **TuningNo.** (Micro-Tuning
>   Number)
>
> This parameter is used to select a musical tuning system. In total, your CP5 or CP50 can replicate seven tuning systems. While the
>   Equal Temperament tuning system has now become standard for pianos, a
>   wide number of other systems were developed over the years before it
>   was adopted, and these systems invariably paved the way for the birth
>   of new musical styles. By selecting a different tuning system, you can
>   play tunes from the corre- sponding styles of music and enjoy their
>   unique nuances.
>
> Setting values:
>
> **00 Equal Temp** (Equal Temperament)
>   The range of pitches in each octave is divided equally into twelve parts, with each half-step evenly spaced in pitch. Today, this is by
>   far the most popular tuning system for pianos.
>
> **01 PureMaj** (Pure Major)
>
> **02 PureMin** (Pure Minor)
>   These two tuning systems preserve the pure mathematical intervals of each scale, especially for triad chords (root, third, fifth). These
>   characteristics are best heard in vocal harmonies — such as choirs and
>   a cappella singing.
>
> **03 Pythag** (Pythagorean)
>   This scale was devised by the famous Greek philosopher, Pythagoras, and is created from a series of perfect fifths, which are
>   collapsed into a single octave. The thirds in this tuning are not so
>   smooth, but the fourths and fifths are beautiful and suitable for
>   certain leads.
>
> **04 MeanTn** (Mean Tone)
>   This scale was created as an improvement on the Pythagorean scale by making the major third interval sound smoother. It was especially
>   popular from the latter part of the 16th century to the end of the
>   18th century, with Handel being one of its most notable users.
>
> **05 Werckmeist** (Werckmeister)
>   **06 Kirnberger**
>   The Werckmeister and Kirnberger scales improve the mean-tone and Pythagorean scales by combining them in different ways. Both are
>   uniquely characterized by the way in which modulation can change the
>   nuances of individual songs. Often applied during the time of Bach and
>   Beethoven, they are used today to reproduce the music of that era on
>   harpsichords.
>
> Page 3 On-screen name (and full name) **TunRoot** (Micro Tuning Root)
>
> This parameter is used to select the root note for the part’s tuning system. No setting is required in the case of certain tuning
>   systems.
>   Setting values: C to B